# Reading .mhtml file from C# program

Tags: c#, mhtml

Is it possible to read .mhtml files from C# program ? or can it be convert to other file format(.txt) so that C# program able to read the content inside. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `File.ReadAllText(path)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the library HtmlAgilityPack for this. It's quite simple to use.

Here is the link to download:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/

https://html-agility-pack.net/from-file

Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
string path = @"C:\Users\tdmanh\Desktop\HtmlAgilityPack.mhtml";
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);
            var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

            Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
```

Comment: Does that definitely handle MHTML files, = HTML in a MIME wrapper?